# Suspender processo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou tentando suspender um processo do `windows` pelo `Delphi`, porém sem sucesso, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
function SuspendProcess(pid:dword):boolean; // Suspende processo pelo PID 
var module,module1:thandle; 
    SusPendProcess:TNTdllApi; 
begin 
  result := false; 
  SetTokenPrivileges; 
  module := LoadLibrary('ntdll.dll'); 
  @SusPendProcess := Getprocaddress(module,'NtSuspendProcess'); 
  if @SusPendProcess <> nil then 
    begin 
      module1 := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,pid); 
      SusPendProcess(module1); 
    end; 
end;
```

Onde informo o `PID`, porém nada ocorre, agora utilizando a ferramenta `PC Hunter`, ele suspende sem nenhum problema.
Seria possível fazer uso da `PSSuspendProcess/ZwSuspendProcess`?
Poderiam me ajudar com algum exemplo? obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Encerrar o processo resolveria o seu problema?
Se resolver tente:

```
PostMessage(FindWindow(<nome_da_tela_principal_do_processo>, nil), WM_CLOSE, 0,0);
```